# Need help with my close link in fancybox modal window to close it

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I want to provide a link to close the fancybox pop-up window.

Here is what I have for code, which does not work, but gives you an idea of what I am accomplishing:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#close-button').click(function(){
      close.click($.fancybox.close);
    });
  });

<p><a href="#" title="Close" id="close-button">&laquo; close</a></p>
```

I am including the fancybox and appropriate jQuery files.

Any help is appreciated.

Fix is:

adding 'type': 'iframe' to it

```
$(".pop-out").fancybox({
  'titlePosition' : 'outside',
  'transitionIn'      : 'fade',
  'transitionOut' : 'none',
  'type'          : 'iframe'
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you simply want to close the box by clicking on `#close-button`, this should be sufficient

```
$('#close-button').click(function(){
  $.fancybox.close();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Isin't it supposed to be like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#close-button').click(function(){
    $.fancybox.close();
  });
});
```

Comment: turned out I needed to set the type to iframe for this to work, had type set to nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Just call $.fancybox.close(); like this Close this window';

Problem solved. No need to use a jquery selector and add more overhead.

Answer (score 0):

The below should do the job.

```
$(function() {
    $('#close-button').click(function(event) {
        $.fancybox.close(true);
    });
});
```